# How do I apply a circular mask to a texture in XNA?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, textures, xna-4.0

I've made a start on a game for Windows Phone 7.1, using a pure XNA 4.0 solution. The game will essentially involve moving around a maze, and I'd like in the top right corner to feature a circle that shows a zoomed-out view of where the player is in the maze.

I've written the code that generates a random maze, and so I can render all of the walls, save this render to a texture in memory and scale that to whatever size it needs to be. But this will be a rectangle.. and I need it to be shown inside a circle.

Any ideas on the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stencil buffer...

First fill the stencil buffer with your mask

Then write the map with the right function in the stencil buffer.

It could be something similar to this:

```
 You fill stencil buffer with a black filled circle rounded by white
```

After that, draw your map with these operations:

```
 StencilFunction = CompareFunction.GreaterEqual
 StencilPass = StencilOperation.Replace
```

You can get more info here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120507161332/http://www.crappycoding.com/2010/08/texture-modification-using-render-targets-with-some-stencil-buffer-action/